# Ignite cache transaction forcibly rolled back

Tags: java, ignite

I'm using transactions for cache operations in Apache Ignite. I'm seeing warnings in my log where a transaction is forcibly rolled back. Like this:

> 16-02-2020 02:09:38.249 [-#115][157   ] WARN 
>   e.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal-[warning 
>   ][ 488] The transaction was forcibly rolled back because a timeout is
>   reached:
>   GridNearTxLocal[xid=fcdfebb4071-00000000-0b85-8094-0000-000000000005,
>   xidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=193298580, order=1581818772943,
>   nodeOrder=5], concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, isolation=SERIALIZABLE,
>   state=ROLLED_BACK, invalidate=false, rollbackOnly=true,
>   nodeId=612b38ca-ffbf-46bf-a27b-00fc68555ff7, timeout=10000,
>   duration=10006]

It looks like this warning appears in my log randomly and not related to my cache operations.

I'm starting my transaction with this:

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();
IgniteTransactions transactions = ignite.transactions();
tx = transactions.txStart(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC, TransactionIsolation.SERIALIZABLE, TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

and ending:

```
  try
  {
      if (tx.state() == TransactionState.ACTIVE)
      {
          if (commit)
              tx.commit();
          else
              tx.rollback();
      }
  } catch (Exception e)
  {
      logger.error(String.format("Error ending transaction for thread(%d) with commit=%b", Thread.currentThread().getId(), commit));

      // re-throw
      throw new Exception(e);
  } finally
  {
      tx.close();
      tx = null;
  }
```

Why am I not getting the rollback-warning as a TransactionRollbackException on my transaction.commit() call? Isn't commit() supposed to wait until the transaction is fully done?

Comment: Maybe you never even reach commit(), instead of hanging on some operation earlier? Maybe you drop some transactions on the floor? Do you have the whole transaction body in catch-all block?

Comment: I will double check this, thought I do catch it all. So this warning shows at the time a timeout happens, and the exception is thrown when I do commit() or rollback() for such a timed transaction?

Comment: Maybe it happens before commit(). Imagine a transaction that never reaches commit() because of uncaught error or logic error or infinite looping.

Comment: Right, I‘ll add some debug log info when the transaction is created to know which transaction is mentioned in the warning. Let‘s say I have a transaction that actually takes long and times out while still in the transaction body, I would then see the Ignite warning in the log first and then get the exception at commit()/rollback(), right?

Comment: Yes, if you ever arrive at commit/rollback, which is not provable for Turing machines :)

Comment: LOL, thanks. I understand how it‘s supposed to work, I‘ll try to debug with more logging. Thanks, you‘ll need to put an answer to my question so I can accept it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you never even reach commit(), instead of hanging on some operation earlier than that. You are not guaranteed to ever reach commit: instead, either locking up earlier, failing to catch unhandled error, or just doing busy work indefinitely.